# how to add Publisher Name in Pyinstaller exe file

Tags: python, windows-installer, pyinstaller, signtool

I work on one project in that code in python script.py and with help of pyinstaller build exe file but issue is that I want to add publisher name in exe file. **FREE**

**exe with publisher name**

I browse on google but I do not get a solution.

- i don't have a code sign certificate.
- I don't have a signtool
- i don't know how to connect a self sign certificate with an exe file.

Please guide me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This link is Answer -> https://mmus.me/blog/certificates/

Thank you for Your Time.

Comment: This is just for test purpose, at the end of the day you still need to buy a real certificate like @TimRoberts said.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this for free.  If you want to sign your executables, you will need to buy a code-signing certificate and use `signtool` to sign them.  Code signing certificates cost about $300 per year.  `signtool` is part of the Windows SDK; you can get it in the free "community" editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I read about Code signing certificates. and I also understand this thing is possible through a Self Code Sign Certificate. Reference :-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Of5nsoJ5JWs. I still have not solved this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can use a self-generated certificate, but other Windows machines will not see it as digitally signed.  It depends on what you're after.

Comment: So what i do for other Windows machines.

Comment: You BUY a certificate.